# Variable regex for ("*" This char may be here or not)VALUE*

Tags: php, regex

If I wanted to search for the following in regex how could I possibly achieve this?

I want to get "value" in each of the strings.

```
this-is-a-set-syntax: VALUE "in 9"(this can be here sometimes and not)

regex: /this-is-a-set-syntax: "(.*)"
```

if I wanted to detect the `"` if it was there then how would I do it? how I thought it should be written:

```
regex: /this-is-a-set-syntax: [?"](.*)[?"]
```

```
this-is-a-set-syntax: "VALUE" (sometimes there is quotes)

this-is-a-set-syntax: "VALUE" (sometimes there is quotes)

this-is-a-set-syntax: VALUE (sometimes there is no quotes at all)
```

if I wanted to try and detect all of them I would have tried something like this.

```
this-is-a-set-syntax: ["|*|]VALUE["|*|][? in [0-9]+|]
```

-- UPDATE -- 
All the below answers but this one is the one that I think fits best.
Having said that they all work and they're all great answers. 
Would you all be able to update your answers with a little bit of explanation for educational purposes.

Thank you this fits best to my answer:

```
this-is-a-set-syntax: ["|*|]?VALUE["|*|]?([? in [0-9]+|])?
```

good but the top is better fit:

```
this-is-a-set-syntax:["* ]*VALUE["* ]*?([? in [0-9]+|])?
```

I like the following one too. I've personally never seen the \1 and interested to know more about this answer too. I'd mark all if I could but I think the top is closest to what I needed.

```
this-is-a-set-syntax:["* ]*VALUE["* ]*?([? in [0-9]+|])?
```

Comment: is [`this`](https://regex101.com/r/dvVhuB/1/) what you're after ?

Comment: May `VALUE` contain whitespace? i.e. `"VAL UE"` or escaped double quotes? i.e. `"VAL\"UE"`

Comment: @CodeManiac Please update your answer below to this regex and I'll mark it as answered

Comment: @TheMan68 do you wish to match `|` too before ? if not then [`Fourth kind's answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57131506/9624435) is better to go with which will take care of balanced `"` if it is must for match, i.e if you don't want to match values like `value"` or `"value`

Comment: in all honest the goal of this is to get VALUE with (.*) between either the ["|*|(an empty string as sometimes there is no double quotes)]

Comment: I'm still having a little problem. check out https://regex101.com/r/D7UwuW/2 as a reference

Comment: You are mixing up the definition of brackets `[...]` with parentheses `(...)` in regular expressions. None of the ones above will suit your problem.

Comment: @TheMan68 what is that little problem will you explain ?

Comment: @revo Yeah I re aliased after trying to adapt the answer to my actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using `[?"](.*)[?"]` will match one of `?"` followed by matching any char 0+ times except a newline and then again one of `?"` which will be the last occurrence in the string. It can over match and does not guarantee an accompanying closing character.

To get value in all of your examples, you might use a capturing group and match an optional double quote `("?)` with a backreference `\1` to account for a matching closing double quote.

If you only want to match value without any whitespaces and the value itself can not contain any of `*|"` you might use:

```
this-is-a-set-syntax:\h+([*|"]?)([^\s*|"]+)\1(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `this-is-a-set-syntax:\h+` Match literally followed by 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `([*|"]?)` Group 1, match an optional `*` `|` or `?`
- `([^\s*|"]+)` Group 2, match 1+ times any char except a whitespace char, `*` `|` or `?`
- `\1` Backreference to what exactly is captured in group 1 to get an accompanying closing char
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B9HYDd/1)

Comment: @TheMan68 In your examples you use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[? in [0-9]+|]` and `["* ]` which will match any of the listed characters. What exactly do you want to match there? Also, should it be the word VALUE literally?

Comment: Shouldn't it match in `this-is-a-set-syntax: VALUE`? See https://regex101.com/r/D7UwuW/4

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes I see it, while updating it I am wondering what the exact rules will be here.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a [**branch reset group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) to match two alternatives where groups share the same indices and match and caprture either the delimited substring or 1 or more non-whitespace chars:

```
this-is-a-set-syntax:\s*(?|(["|*])(.*?)\1|()(\S+))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aBbFrd/1)

**Details**

- `this-is-a-set-syntax:` - some string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?|` - start of the branch reset group

  - `(["|*])` - Group 1: one of the specified chars: `"`, `|` or `*`
  - `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
  - `\1` - same value as in Group 1
- `|` - or

  - `()` - a dummy Group 1 matching an empty string
  - `(\S+)` - Group 2: one or more chars other than whitespace
- `)` - end of the branch reset group.